# How to trigger mdmenu on click of span or anchor tag in angular2

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu

I have the following **mdmenu** in my Angular2 application :

```
<md-menu #appMenu="mdMenu">
 <button md-menu-item> Item1 </button>
 <button md-menu-item> Item2 </button>
 <button md-menu-item> Item3 </button>
</md-menu>
```

**How can I trigger this on click of a span or an anchor tag ?**

I am able to trigger it using md-button like this :

```
<button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">Menu</button>
```

I want to achieve the same functionality using span or anchor tag.
PS :  I cant use button inside span or anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just to replace `button` with `a` (or `span`):

```
<a [mdMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">Menu</a>
<md-menu #appMenu="mdMenu">
 <button md-menu-item> Item1 </button>
 <button md-menu-item> Item2 </button>
 <button md-menu-item> Item3 </button>
</md-menu>
```

you can style it with CSS as desired.
plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/YR9hTjActXL1Z79jXkH1?p=preview

Comment: Why md-button with the anchor tag?

Comment: any element can trigger menu open, what is important is [mdMenuTrigger] value, which points to the menu to be opened. So, if you write just `<span [mdMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">Menu</span>` it will also work

Comment: I got it now. Thanks a lot  :)